# How do I make camera follow player only in a certain scene?

Tags: unity, c#

In my other scenes I made it so the camera doesn't follow the player, I only want the camera to follow the player in one scene. How do I do that?
This is my follow cam script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CamFollowPlayer : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField]
    GameObject player;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x,
GameObject.Find("Shrump").transform.position.y,
transform.position.z);

    }
}
```

Comment: Would it not suffice to simply put your followcam script on the camera in one scene, and not put it on the cameras in other scenes? What's the complication you're trying to overcome? Are you using additive scene loading or DontDestroyOnLoad to carry a single camera through from scene to scene? Or are you instantiating the cameras from a shared prefab? You'll need to tell us more about your situation since we don't know how your game is structured.

Comment: @DMGregory well when I put a follow cam script on the scene it doesnt work because I need my player in the scene to put the camera on it, but my player starts in one scene and walks into that scene later

Comment: So you're really asking how to assign the player reference to your camera follow script when the camera loads in the new scene, is that correct? Is the follow target just a public variable on your camera follow script, or is it doing something more involved? Do you currently have a unique script or tag on your player character that we could use to identify it in the crowd?

Comment: @DMGregory well I tagged the camera Player and tagged the player as Player, so now the camera follows the player but only when I jump up, but it doesnt follow the player if I move left and right.

Comment: It sounds a lot like you should include this information and the relevant code in your question. Use the edit button so you can get legible code formatting.

Comment: Once you show an effort of clarifying your question I will remove my downvote.

Comment: and can you tell me how can I clarfiy

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close here. You just need to...

- Capture the reference to the player in Start, rather than searching every frame
- Apply the follow effect on all axes, not only on the y axis
- Apply an offset so your camera doesn't embed inside the player object, but sits at a controllable distance & direction away

Like so:

```
public class CamFollowPlayer : MonoBehaviour {

    // Control where the camera wants to position itself relative
    // to the player in worldspace (other spaces are available too)
    public Vector3 offset = new Vector3(0, 1, -10);

    [SerializeField]
    GameObject player;

    // Caching the player reference in Start saves search costs later.
    void Start () {
        player = GameObject.Find("Shrump");
    }

    // LateUpdate is called after all Updates 
    // (so the camera can move in response to the player's movement this frame)
    void LateUpdate () {    
        transform.position = player.transform.position + offset;    
    }
}
```

Note that looking up gameobjects by name can be fragile, [leading to obscure bugs](https://twitter.com/D_M_Gregory/status/672973048899702784) if the naming or spawning structure of your game ever changes. A better alternative is to `FindObjectOfType` to search for the player control script or something similar that is uniquely attached to the player.

---

Also, for future reference, please note that abusive language like this is generally not a good way to make people want to help you. If you want free help from users here, you should be prepared to treat them with respect, and be patient when your question does not get answered immediately.

[image]
[image]

Comment: thats a good one